# Regex Validation to exclude a group

Tags: regex

I have two scenarios where I need two regex.

```
/vendors?(\-[a-z]*)*/

/vendor-staff?(\-[a-z]*)*/
```

My problem is that first one interfere with second one:
With the first one I need to capture cases like: vendor, vendor-add, vendor-edit, vendor-list;
Second one needs to capture cases where: vendor-staff-add, vendor-staff-edit exists only;

How can I do that? I tried several options without success.

I tried to validate those here: https://regexr.com/3uddc

Thank you

Comment: Wiktor Thank you, works! You are correct, I don't need it in here! I tried as a solution (?!-) but this didn't worked, and I didn't thought to use the entire string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a negative lookahead `(?!-staf)` after `vendor` in the first regex:

```
vendor(?!-staf)s?(-[a-z]*)*
```

To prevent consecutive hyphens, you need to replace the `[a-z]*` with `[a-z]+` pattern:

```
vendor(?!-staf)s?(-[a-z]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VKIkH3/1)

**Details**

- `vendor` - a literal substring
- `(?!-staf)` - no `-staf` substring allowed right after `vendor`
- `s?` - an optional `s`
- `(-[a-z]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of `-` and then 1+ lowercase ASCII letters.